# FB API PHP curl_setopt_array(): The usage of the @filename API for file uploading is deprecated

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Have a problem with FB PHP API and php 5.5 with uploading photo to server. When using method :

```
 private function _upload( $type = '', $path = '', $message = '', $aid = '' ) {
        try {

            if ( !in_array( $type, array( 'photos', 'videos' ) ) ) {
                throw new \Exception( 'Error: Incorrect type ' );
            }

            if ( !self::getFB()->getUser() ) {
                throw new \Exception( 'Error: No user' );
            }

            if ( empty( $path ) ) {
                throw new \Exception( 'Error: path is empty' );
            }
            if ( !file_exists( realpath( $path ) ) ) {
                throw new \Exception( 'Error: file doesn\'t exists' );
            }


            if ( !empty( $aid ) ) {
                $url = "/" . $aid . "/" . $type;
            } else {
                $url = '/' . self::getFB()->getUser() . '/' . $type;
            }

            var_dump( array( $url, 'POST',

                    array(
                        'image'   => '@' . realpath( $path ),
                        'message' => $message,
                    )
                )
            );

            self::getFB()->setFileUploadSupport( TRUE );

            $ret_obj = self::getFB()->api( $url, 'POST', array(
                    'image'   => '@' . realpath( $path ),
                    'message' => $message,
                )
            );
            return $ret_obj[ 'id' ];
        } catch ( \Exception $e ) {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

I get error : curl_setopt_array(): The usage of the @filename API for file uploading is deprecated. Please use the CURLFile class instead

Comment: You should create a bug report asking them to update the SDK to take this change into account, https://developers.facebook.com/bugs Btw., is that really an _error_ message that breaks your script, or is it just a warning? (“Deprecated” means will not work any more at some point in the future, but still does for now, so this should just be a warning and not a script breaking error.)

Comment: Because of settings on server this creates an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using PHP 5.5 with the old way of uploading over CURL. Check out the differences at https://wiki.php.net/rfc/curl-file-upload

## Old

```
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$args['file'] = '@filename.png';
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $args);
```

## New

```
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$args['file'] = new CurlFile('filename.png', 'image/png');
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $args);
```