# Error POST file PHP cURL

Tags: php, post, curl

I'm using PHP Version 5.3.3-7+squeeze19 (At work).

I'm trying to POST a file using cURL but the response of the server is "false, file no received". This make me think that I'm writing the correct cURL code but is not sending the file.

```
private static function sendPostRequestTest(){

    $url = "http://devapi.xxxx.com/vx/uploadFile/xx/xx-xx-xxx?authToken=brbfgkw33d3d3d3";

    $file_name_with_full_path = realpath('data/fileTest.jpeg');

    $post = array('file'=>'@'.$file_name_with_full_path);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    $result=curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);

}
```

I've been searching for a week and I can't find any reason why is not sending the file. The path is correct (I guess) because I did verify it using file_exist function.

Comment: Please use `CURLFile`, using `@` prefix is deprecated as of PHP 5.6. Sure, you're using 5.3, but that version was EOL'ed a while back: upgrade your PHP version! [to 5.5 or later](http://php.net/eol.php)

Comment: Link for @EliasVanOotegem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18482236/fb-api-php-curl-setopt-array-the-usage-of-the-filename-api-for-file-uploadin/19667520

Comment: I can't update PHP because my boss doesn't want to. And yes the parameters are correct because the API(test server) is giving to me a response (XML response) "<response>No file received</response>" So the URL is fine, the thing is that I have to send any file (jpeg, csv, etc) as a parameter and I guess the API is not getting the file or at least I'm not sending it properly

Comment: I'm going to try and bring life to this issue, because I'm in the exact same situation. if you print out `curl_errno()` what error number do you get? I get `43`

Comment: Thanks mark for your message, well.. We put that on hold but soneer or later we have to have a look to it.. I'm on holidays at the moment though but would be great to find out the solution to this. I didn't print the error by the way! Because it didn't give me any. Just the server response as "false". It looks like isn't sending any file. Let's try to find out what's going on.